# Footer HTML overlapping items in small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a footer. When the page is loaded in big screens there are no overlap. When are used small screens the footer overlaps with items (the download buttons), this because in small screens the footer becomes higher (the text will be wrapped into many lines).

This is what I see using different screens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code of the footer is:

```
<div class="footer" >
    <div class="container-fluid" style="font-size: 90%">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 offset-1 text-center">
                <a href="http://www.my.site.com">
                    <img style="max-height: 25px; margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: 15%" src="/images/resources/logo-blah.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <span class="text-muted">Long text here... 
                    <a href="http://my.site.com">BLAH</a>. © <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                <a href="http://my.site.com">
                    <img style="max-height: 25px; margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: 15%" src="/images/resources/BLAH_logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the style is:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #177396, #0cc1b3);
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #CCC;
}
```

> The question

I would like the element to remain below the last element (the one above it) without overlapping it. Is there a way to avoid the overlapping even when the footer element stretches upwards?

Comment: You've stated your problem, but you haven't actually asked a question. At the moment, the first thing you need to do is decide on what you want to happen. That's a UX problem, not a programming problem. The programming comes when you come to implement the design you come up with.

Comment: Question added, I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Someone said it's not a programming problem, but a user exeprience. It could be, but from my point of view it was a programming problem and I solved it through programming. HTML and CSS are two true programming languages.

Comment: I was not trying to imply that writing HTML and CSS was not coding (they aren't programming languages, but they are code, and how you use them is on topic here). The question, when I made it, didn't say what you wanted to achieve. It was phrased in a way where the answer could be "Make X smaller" or "Put X under Y" or "Add scroll bars". The matter of *how* you write code to make X smaller, put X under Y, or add scroll bars *is* a coding problem, but the question hadn't asked any of those.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid absolute positioning of such main layout elements. If you have sticky header or footer in the layout, you will face such problems on smaller screens.

One possible solution is to get rid of the `position: absolute` inside a media query to only target mobile devices (or those with a small screen). That way the footer will only be visible after scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Only in this specific case/problem, I solved it by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
@media all and (min-width:0px) and  (max-width: 799px) {

   .myElement {
       margin-top: 350px;
   }

}
```

Distinguishing then the small screens from the big ones, varying accordingly the style with the most suitable one.